# How to create USDZ file with animation to be used in RealityKit

Tags: animation, blender, realitykit, usdz, reality-converter

I am facing an issue with USDZ file  that needs to be shown in iOS RealityKit. The USDZ file is having animation that needs to animate differently depending on which button is pressed.

Unfortunately, while running app, implemented realityKit the animation array is coming blank, whereas file downloaded from apple QuickLook works perfectly.

In Apple USDZ tool, it failed with **usdzchecker**.

We tried everything from root correction to export the file, however it is still not resolved.

Could anyone please help to figure out what's different with our USDZ file than the one downloaded from apple website, or let me know the steps required to create animated usdz file that can be used in realitykit and animate on button click?

Below are the files:

Working USDZ (Downloaded from apple): https://developer.apple.com/augmented-reality/quick-look/models/drummertoy/toy_drummer_idle.usdz

My file: (Created in **Blender**) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UibIKBy2fx4q0XxSNodOwQZMLgktKiKF/view?usp=sharing

[image]